# How to make an error message div sticky?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, primefaces, sticky

An error message(which is rendered conditionally) is displayed on top of the screen and if the user is at the bottom of the screen, he always has to scroll up to view the error.

So I am trying to display that error within the view of the user.

I am using Primefaces `p:messages` to display the error.
I also tried using the `p:sticky` component to make the error message sticky.

Like:

`<p:messages id="errorMessage"/>
 <p:sticky target="errorMessage"/>`

It does not seem to be working with that.
Is there something I can do with primefaces or should I just use plain CSS and jQuery to get this working?

Comment: Why don't you use <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"/>?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display: fixed;` rule to that element. It should work.

If you can change the `position` of element using `top`, `left`, `right` or `bottom` rule. Please make sure you provide higher `z-index` value to element otherwise it may be hidden by some other elements with high `z-index`.

Comment: That does not seem to do the trick.
To which element did you mean? `p:messages` generates the below structure:
`<div id="errormessagesid" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite">
<div class="ui-messages-error ui-corner-all">
<span class="ui-messages-error-icon" style=""></span>
<span class="ui-messages-error-summary">Email must be filled.</span>
</div>
</div`

Comment: Using `position:fixed` and `top;0` and `left:0` to `p` tag, you can achieve your desire result. Did you try?

Answer (score -1):

The correct CSS attribute you are looking for is:

```
position: fixed;
```

However, you may also want to add z-index, and positioning value as such (this will give you a good starting to then position to your liking):

```
position: fixed;
/*this value can be larger or smaller depending on other elements*/
z-index: 9; 
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Be aware that if this element is in parent container that has `position: relative`, this element wont stick as you expect.

Also you should add a class name to your sticky element, to be able to target it. E.G.

`<p:sticky class="sticky" target="errorMessage" />`

Your final css with that class name should look like this:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no "class" attribute for the for `p:sticky`.

Comment: Your answer contains 'errors' most likely cause by not having JSF or PrimeFaces knowledge

Answer (score -2):

You Can Use This

```
Use Position:fixed property
```

Demo Here https://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/tddsL50c/1/

Here is The Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#koo").fadeOut();

$("#foo").click(function(){

$(".alertbox").fadeIn();


})


})
```

Here is The CSS

```
.alertbox{width:300px; height:100px; padding:30px; position:fixed;top:2%; left:2%; 
margin-top:-10px;margin-left:10px; background:#000; color:#fff; display:none}
```